# python xml etree get all subtext of element

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml document like:

```
<root>
 <el> rawr
  <p> blah blah <b>important</b> blah blah </p> what
 </el>
</root>
```

I need to extract the string:

```
'rawr <p> blah blah <b>important</b> blah blah </p> what'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes going through the motions of typing up a question for stackoverflow helps me think it through and discover the answer for myself.  Since I already had the question typed up, figured I'd go ahead and post the answer I came up with.  =c)

```
et = ET.parse(my_xml)
node = et.find('el')
"".join([node.text] + [ET.tostring(e) for e in node])
```